# JSON Conversation

Tags: android, json, web-services

I have a JSON which is returned from a Web Service Developed in PHP but I need help to converting this JSON to JSONArray in Android

{"Name":"John","Contact":"3331234567"}{"Name":"Doe","Contact":"3017654321"}{"Name":"Smith","Contact":"3001234765"}

How can i convert this String returned from URL to JSONArray

Comment: Hello! This is invalid JSON. Is it possible, that it contains newline between individual elements? Like this:
`{"Name": ...}\n{"Name": ...}`. If so, then it could be [JSONLines](http://jsonlines.org) format, with which we can work.

Comment: Is the PHP web service yours? It looks like it needs some work.

Comment: Yes this Web Service is mine

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to return it from the web service as a standard JSON Array, which means:
`[{"Name":"John","Contact":"3331234567"},{"Name":"Doe","Contact":"3017654321"},{"Name":"Smith","Contact":"3001234765"}]`
In this case you can parse it with any common json parser easily (gson, org.json, any other).
Returning it as you do it now produces invalid JSON - just put it to any online JSON validator and it will complain about this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys for giving me an idea to fix this problem. I have figured it out bu conceding a string e.g: "n" while writing response on my web service now i can split this on my Android App.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I suggested you to create json file in standard mode
like this:

```
{   
   "USER":[ {
               "Name":"John",
               "Contact":"3331234567"
            }
            {
               "Name":"Doe",
               "Contact":"3017654321"
            }
            {
               "Name":"Smith",
               "Contact":"3001234765"
            }]
}
```

if you have not any field more , you can remove "USER":

**2.** You should use json parser library like GSON

**3.**use "pojo" site for create json model in java like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/